# Javascript, jQuery scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a scroll effect when the user scrolls up or down.
What I intend to do is scroll by the maximum possible amount(reach top/bottom if screen.height is bigger than what remains)
My code for now intends just simple scrolls but it still doesnt really work. sometimes it doesn't go down or it get's stuck an I can't scroll anywhere. anyone who can help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var height = Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height());
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    var d_scroll = Math.min(screen.height, height - $(window).scrollTop() - screen.height);
    //alert(d_scroll);
    $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + (d_scroll) }, 1000);

} else if(st < lastScrollTop) {
    var d_scroll2 = Math.min(screen.height, $(window).scrollTop());
    $(window).animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - d_scroll2 }, 1000);

}// else { alert(screen.height + st); alert(height);}
lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
});
});
```

Comment: 'But it still doesn't really work'. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Could you provide us the html code?

Comment: Try moving your window.onscroll function outside the document.onready function.